# MVC3 Multiple Conditions in where Clause

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, null

I have the following in my Controller

```
var workshop = registerDB.Workshops.Single(w => w.WorkshopID == id);
ViewBag.Enrollments = registerDB.Carts.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(User.Identity.Name));
```

and this in my view

```
@{ 
    //var carts = Model.Carts.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(User.Identity.Name));
     var carts =  ViewBag.Enrollments;
     var timeSlot = Model.TimeSlot;
    }

   @{
foreach (var item in carts)

{
    if (item != null)
    {
    if (timeSlot == item.Workshop.TimeSlot)
    {
        <h3>@timeSlot</h3>
    }
    }
     else
    {
        <h3>Does not Exist</h3>
    }

}
}
```

each time `ViewBag.Enrollments = registerDB.Carts.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(User.Identity.Name));` returns no results, I get an error saying `System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.` and this line is highlighted

```
if (timeSlot == item.Workshop.TimeSlot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `.ToList()` in the controller to eagerly fetch the results:

```
ViewBag.Enrollments = registerDB
    .Carts
    .Where(x => x.Username.Equals(User.Identity.Name))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: How do i check if the ViewBag.Enrollments in the event the User hasn't made any selections?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking that `item != null` but not that `item.Workshop != null` before trying to use it. It would appear that is perhaps the error, but why it's raising `InvalidOperationException` rather than `NullReferenceException` I don't know.

Try:

```
if (item != null && item.Workshop != null)
{
    if (timeSlot == item.Workshop.TimeSlot)
    {
        <h3>@timeSlot</h3>
    }
}
```

Comment: @EdgarOchieng' - Not sure then.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put the single call in your model:

```
workshops workshop = registerDB.Workshops.Single(w => w.WorkshopID == id);
```

And then in your controller set the ViewBag:

```
try
{
ViewBag.Enrollments = workshop.Carts.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(User.Identity.Name));
}
catch
{
ViewBag.Enrollments = "There are no results";
}
```